# Access Windows 10 localhost from OSX using Parallels

Tags: macos, windows-10, parallels

I'm running a Windows 10 VM using Parallels. I'm building an API on the windows machine and a mobile app on OSX. I need to call the Windows localhost from OSX in order to test out my API calls. Is this possible with Win 10 and if so what are the steps?

Comment: I could not able to access VM localhost:8080, I don't know the issue. I am able to connect it when I was using Win 7 Parallels, but when I update it to Win 10 parallels, it is not accessible. Please let us know if you find any solution to this